# Why do nth-of-type elements fail to work at third-element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some question about Css nth-of-type.
In the code below,
`nth-of-type(2)` and `nth-of-type(3)` is work ,
but `nth-of-type(4)` and `nth-of-type(5)` can't work.

Is there anything wrong in my code?

```
<div id="insideCircle">
      <div class="outsideNumber"></div>
      <div class="outsideNumber"></div>
      <div class="outsideNumber"></div>
      <div class="outsideNumber"></div>
      <div class="outsideNumber"></div>
<div>
```

```
.outsideNumber{
  width: 0px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.outsideNumber:nth-of-type(2){
  width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(30deg);
}
.outsideNumber:nth-of-type(3){
  width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(60deg);
};

.outsideNumber:nth-of-type(4){
  width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(90deg);
};

.outsideNumber:nth-of-type(5){
  width: 1px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(120deg);
}
```

When I disable `nth-of-type(2)` the 3 and 4 element work but 5 not.
It seems like `nth-of-type(4)` can be select but when it become the third element,it's broken.
I wonder why nth-of-type broken after the third element?

and also I want to know is `nth-of-type` work on class?
I see some document say it can only select html tag.
If it can't work on class,then why the `.outsideNumber:nth-of-type(2)` work?

Comment: Your code has error. Remove the semicolon after the nth-of-type(3)

Comment: And to add to what @JinuKurian said, same issue for `nth-of-type(4)` and the last `<div>` should be `</div>`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the semicolon at the end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code is correct only.
you have been given a semi-colon, so you have to remove that's it.

```
.outsideNumber:nth-of-type(3){  
  width: 1px;   
  background-color: yellow; 
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(60deg);    
}
.outsideNumber:nth-of-type(4){  
  width: 1px;   
  background-color: green;  
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(90deg);    
}
```

I hope this worked for you.